# Fancybox realign on content show/hide

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using FancyApp, another version of FancyBox, to open a webpage using its ajax loader. On my page there are some content which show/hide (style=display:"none/block") on some button action. When the content show/hide the fancyBox does not realign itself. It remains at same position where it was when the page was loaded. What I need to realign the fancyBox when its page's change its size. Is there and event available where I can realign the fancybox?

Comment: I have tried autoCenter:true and autoResize:true, but no success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After show/hide the content, I have called following function, and it works perfectly:

```
$.fancybox.reposition();
```